# JBoss7 Deployment on Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, jboss

I have JBoss7 running on a server and a Java Application. I am deploying war files using JBoss7 console system.

What I would like to know is where are these files really placed as when I go to the deployment folder the deployed files are not there.

I am asking this because I have a property file placed under the configuration folder and it seems that this file is not being read as I am having problems using the java I have created.

For you to know more in detail, when I installed locally JBoss on a pc and deployed the same project (but using Netbeans) it worked. The thing is that as I said I installed JBoss on ubuntu and would like to deploy the same project there.

Would appreciate your help.

Regards,

Keith Spiteri

Comment: I believe JBoss creates temporary folders for deployments.

Comment: and what is the name of this temporary folder please

Comment: I am seeing temporary files under standalone/tmp/work/jboss.web/default-host/<war name>